# Which module version should I use for specific python version?

Tags: python, module, python-3.7

I have Python 3.7.10, but when I try to import Georasters I keep getting the following error

```
Can't find requested entry point: GDALRegisterMe
Can't find requested entry point: GDALRegister_nitf
Can't find requested entry point: GDALRegisterMe
Can't find requested entry point: GDALRegister_nitf
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\environment_name\lib\site-packages\pysal\explore\segregation\network\network.py:16: UserWarning: You need pandana and urbanaccess to work with segregation's network module
You can install them with  `pip install urbanaccess pandana` or `conda install -c udst pandana urbanaccess`
  "You need pandana and urbanaccess to work with segregation's network module\n"
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\environment_name\lib\site-packages\pysal\model\spvcm\abstracts.py:10: UserWarning: The `dill` module is required to use the sqlite backend fully.
  from .sqlite import head_to_sql, start_sql
```

I tried to install pandana and urban access using `conda install -c udst pandana urbanaccess` but I am getting the following error:

```
    The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
    The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
    
      - conda-forge/label/cf201901/win-64::fiona==1.8.4=py37h0d92105_1001
      - defaults/noarch::geopandas==0.6.1=py_0
      - conda-forge/label/cf201901/noarch::georasters==0.5.15=py_0
      - defaults/noarch::pysal==2.1.0=py_0
      - conda-forge/label/cf201901/noarch::rasterstats==0.13.0=py_0
    failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
    Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Determining conflicts:   0%|                                                                                                                                                         | 0/6 [00:00<?, ?it/s]|failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - urbanaccess -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: esri/win-64::python==3.7.10=0

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify that.    
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

My plan is to install versions of each library that works with Python 3.7.10. Does anyone else have a suggestion?

Comment: `pip install urbanaccess`?

Comment: According to the error, don't use conda install here, maybe you can go to command prompt or terminal and `pip install`

Comment: It returns: ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
georasters 0.5.15 requires GDAL, which is not installed.

GDAL is installed though

Comment: I am getting this error now: 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
- conda-forge/label/cf201901/win-64::proj4==5.2.0=hfa6e2cd_1001